# How to use JSONB_SET for updating JSONB Column in PostgreSQL Procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jsonb

I am using a Stored Procedure to update a JSONB column in the table and it does not seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Many Thanks.

My Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE mn_customer (
cust_id int,
f_name varchar(20),
l_name varchar(20),
json_payload jsonb);
```

My SPROC is:

```
create or replace procedure update_mn_customer
(
update_cust_id int DEFAULT null,
update_json_payload jsonb DEFAULT null
)
language plpgsql as
$proc$
begin
    
    update mn_customer
        set json_payload = jsonb_set(json_payload, update_json_payload)
    where  cust_id = update_cust_id;
    commit;

end
$proc$;
```

My call to procedure to perform an Update is:

```
call update_mn_customer(
1998, to_jsonb('{"jsonpayload-fld1": "John Davis", "jsonpayload-fld2": "Lenny Pascoe","jsonpayload-fld3": "Undefined"}'::text)
);
```

I keep getting the Error:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, jsonb) does not exist
LINE 2:         set json_payload = jsonb_set(json_payload, update_js...
                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  update mn_customer
        set json_payload = jsonb_set(json_payload, update_json_payload)
    where  cust_id = update_cust_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_mn_customer(integer,jsonb) line 8 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) when you want to replace only one part of the jsonb data identified by a path with a new jsonb value. In your case, it seems that `update_json_payload` is the new value for the `json_payload` column so you just have to update it :

```
update mn_customer
   set json_payload = update_json_payload
 where  cust_id = update_cust_id ;
```

Then you don't need to commit inside the plpgsql procedure.